# Obtener un dato de un JSON en C#

Tags: c#, json

Lo que ocurre es que estoy intentando obtener el dato de un campo de una tabla la cuestion es que ese campo tiene insertado un JSON(id, nombre, cantidad y valor) me gustaria como tal obtener de ese JSON el nombre para asignar ese dato a una variable y usarla luego. No he encontrado formas como podria hacerlo?

Este vendria siendo el JSON:

```
[{"id":"5","name":"DUMAKI","cant":"2","val":"20000"},{"id":"6","name":"FILADELFIA","cant":"1","val":"15000"}]
```

Ya cree un objeto con parametros iguales a los del JSON con sus get y set intento deserializarlo para luego usar por ejemplo solo el name de la siguiente forma:

```
Objeto_puro json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Objeto_puro>(Convert.ToString(dtblPedidos.Rows[0].ItemArray[1]));
```

pero me sale este error:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Sushi2Home.Objeto_puro' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: el problema es el acceso a la tabla para obtener el json, o solo trabajar con esa estructura? podrias poner como seria la estructura del json

Comment: Hola el problema es trabajar con la estructura 
[{"id":"5","name":"DUMAKI","cant":"2","val":"20000"},{"id":"6","name":"FILADELFIA","cant":"1","val":"15000"}]
este seria el JSON y un campo de la tabla que se llama pedidos tiene ese JSON como valor he buscado tutoriales pero no estoy muy seguro de como obtener un valor en especifico, guardarlo en un string para poder utilizarlo luego ejemplo el Name que seria DUMAKI y FILADELFIA.

Comment: edita la pregunta agregando esta info adicional asi puede volver abrirse

Comment: La reabro.. que tiene esta linea dtblPedidos.Rows[0].ItemArray[1]??? porque dice que eso no es un json.. estas seguro que hay un json ahi? lo podes mostrar?

Comment: Mmm deja y reviso porque cuando hago el select en la base de datos me muestra esto : [{"id":"5","name":"DUMAKI","cant":"2","val":"20000"},{"id":"6","name":"FILADELFIA","cant":"1","val":"15000"}]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
JIList<Objeto_puro> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Objeto_puro>>(json.ToString());
```

El principal problema que tienes es que el json que manejas como al principio y final tiene corchetes `[]`, es decir, que es una lista, por lo cual no puedes devolver un objeto sino una lista de un objeto que después tienes que recorrer para poder acceder a sus propiedades.

`dtblPedidos.Rows[0].ItemArray[1]`: este objeto tienes que transformarlo a un string para poder hacer el casteo a la lista de objetos que te comenté al principio.